# Agregate JSON events into an array in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm new to Azure Stream Analytics and query language. I have an ASA job which reads json data coming from my IoT Hub and feeds it to different functions based on one of the values. This is what I have now:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    storage
FROM
    iothub

SELECT
    *
INTO
    storageQueueFunction
FROM
    iothub
WHERE
    recType LIKE '3'

SELECT
    *
INTO
    deviceTwinD2CFunctionApp
FROM
    iothub
WHERE
    recType LIKE '50'
    
SELECT
    *
INTO
    heartbeatD2CFunctionApp
FROM
    iothub
WHERE
    recType LIKE '51'

SELECT
    *
INTO
    ackC2D
FROM
    iothub
WHERE
    recType LIKE '54'
```

I'm pretty sure this could be done more efficiently but it's working for now.

My problem is that when a large number of events come in with recType 54, I think it is overloading my Function App "ackC2D".

My idea is to batch these types of events into a json array using something like a rolling window of 5 seconds, then send that array to the output where I can parse through the array event by event.

I haven't been able to find anything like this online, the closest I can find is aggregating data then outputting a calculation on the aggregate.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring the Azure function output, you have the ability to specify 'Max batch size' and 'Max batch count' properties. If lot of input events arrive rapidly, keeping a high value for these properties will result in fewer calls to your Azure Function output (by automatically batching many outputs events in a single HTTP request).